# Callback for System Events e.g. ARP Entry Addition

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, network-programming, monitoring

I am looking at creating a network monitoring system for Windows 7/8. My process needs to be able to monitor events e.g. Addition of a new ARP Entry, Network Up/Down on different interfaces, DHCP success/renew etc.

Is there a way by which a program can register to get all these system wide events without having to Poll using the standard APIs? I definitely do not want to sleep and keep reading the ARP table to check if a new entry is added.

I am coding in Visual C++.